# Chrome: Not responding to slow clicks on links or buttons

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a site that can be viewed on a certain touchscreen kiosks (for interests sake a raspberry pi).

If a user clicks a button, say 0.4s press), which happens often, it focuses the link/button etc instead of clicking it. The user then things nothing has happened.

Is there a chrome policy or CSS that one can apply to disable selecting a link etc with a slow press?

I tried the following but they did not help:

```
        touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
        user-select: none;
```

And I hunted through the Chrome policies here:
https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#CursorHighlightEnabled

PS only concerned with Chrome

Comment: Try `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color) and `-webkit-touch-callout: none;` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-touch-callout)

Comment: @dziku86 thanks for that rare information. I am using chrome though, and thats where I see the problem, whereas thats a safari property.

Comment: Sorry, now I understand your problem. Maybe try `tabindex="-1"` on links/buttons if you don't need keyboard accessibility on those touchscreen kiosks. Idk if this will work, just a guess.

Comment: @dziku86 thanks for the comment. I actually tried it already and it didnt work for some reason.